# Css3 Animation: Moving Images Top to Bottom

Tags: css, css-animations

Asked a similar question to this yesterday, where Zeaklous helped me out with a good answer that worked for animating water moving seamlessly left to right.

so i tried to apply the same thing to a image moving top to bottom seamlessly, thought using the same method would work but i feel like im missing something.

the html is:

```
<div id="waterfall"></div>
```

the css is:

```
#waterfall {
background: url(img/waterfall.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 100%;
height: 1200px;
position: absolute;
top: 1150px;
right: 870px;
z-index: 5;
-webkit-transition: flow 3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: flow 3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: flow 3s ease-out;
    transition: flow 3s ease-out;

animation: flow 2000s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes flow {
100% {background-position: 0 0;}
0% {background-position: 0 100000%;}
}
```

had some problems when i made the width a set 45px, cant get any animations to work. so i set it to 100% but then it just disappears and i cant find it again.

if i change the animation to horizontal, it works but only with width:100%, the moment i try make it vertical movement is wont work.

what am i missing here that is different for vertical animations?

any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe much of the issue you're having has to do with `background-repeat: no-repeat;`. The way the animation is set up, it uses repeats to create the flow. When you have `no-repeat` on, it discontinues the flow due (because it relies on the image repeating). [Here is a demo](http://cssdeck.com/labs/vn4qg7b5) of your code with simply this line taken out and the % in `flow` fixed (scroll down to see the animation due to your absolute positioning). You can see what it does now, I'm not sure how you want it to look in the end.

There should be no issue changing it from horizontal animation to vertical animation, as seen by this new demo showing both effects separate. All I did was switch the x and y values in the `after` animation: http://cssdeck.com/labs/mjsrldib If you put `background-repeat: no-repeat;` back in you can see the problem it creates

**EDIT** your question prompted me to try and make something that fell like a waterfall but still moved sideways like your water element. [Here is what I came up with](http://cssdeck.com/labs/ecjn29me) in the short time I worked on it. It could prove useful somehow

Comment: ok so i changed it, removed the no repeats, and got it working BUT, i dont know why, if i change the background image to the web version you have, it works perfectly BUT, if i use my image, the image loads but wont move at all, any idea why? heres the screenshot, the line of water is the image, its sized at 45px width and height is 1200px but it wont move. http://prntscr.com/1i19nn

Comment: solved. remade the graphic but as a smaller size, not entirely sure why that would have changed it though.